# How to use current datetime variable dynamically in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have set a variable as 'currentdate' with string datatype and given the following default value
[image]

In the copy data action, I wrote the below sequel query

```
@concat('
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
   [',variables('schema'),'].[',if(variables('custom_table_list_flag'),item(),item().name),'] 
WHERE 
    UPDATE_DATE >  DATEADD(DAY,-1,CAST(''[',variables('currentdate'),']'' AS DATE))
    AND UPDATE_DATE <= CAST(''[',variables('currentdate'),']'' AS DATE);')
```

however ADF is returning the following error

> Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedFileOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The file operation is failed, upload file failed at path: '/Parent/UAT'.,Source=mscorlib,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=241,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=241,State=1,Message=Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.,},],'

Answer (score 1):

[image]

When there is an attempt to convert a string into a date or time value, but the string does not represent a valid date or time, the above error will occur. You can use the following expression:

```
DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(''', variables('currentdate'), ''' AS DATE))'
```

**Output:**

[image]

```
CAST(''', variables('currentdate'),''' AS DATE
```

**Output:**

[image]

Instead of the expression below:

```
DATEADD(DAY,-1,CAST(''[',variables('currentdate'),']'' AS DATE)
CAST(''[',variables('currentdate'),']'' AS DATE);')
```

The **`currentdate`** variable has a value of `@formatDateTime(utcnow())`. You will be able to run the query successfully without any error.

Comment: Hi it's still giving the same error.
I used the below query
@concat('
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
   [',variables('schema'),'].[',if(variables('custom_table_list_flag'),item(),item().name),'] 
WHERE 
    UPDATE_DATE >  DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(''', variables('currentdate'), ''' AS DATE))
    AND UPDATE_DATE <= CAST(''', variables('currentdate'),''' AS DATE)')

Comment: once check individual condition query using look with select command in lookup activity then you will be able to know the problem.